# Is it possible for multiple modes to combine their fontifications?

Tags: font-lock

For example, a buffer has some major mode and it does its own fontification.

If I turn on a minor mode A then it adds its own fontification which changes the existing fontification by  changing the apperance of some characters which are already fontified by the major mode.

Then if I turn off the minor mode it removes its own fontification and for those characters which the major mode fontified originally the original fontification is restored.

Is it possible for a minor mode to change fontification in such a layer-like way, so that it overshadows the existing fontification, but this layer of fontification can be removed cleanly if the mode is turned off?

Comment: I have got the impression that this is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do what you ask for? Why does the way it is not work for you?

Comment: @Tobias: Here's an example: if you use orgmode then you know it uses dashes for table lines and it also colors the table with font lock. Suppose, I want to replace the dash character with a `─` character for better visual appearance (the lines will be continuous) by a minor mode which shows tables with `─` character when turned on, and with the default dashes when it's turned off.  How can I implement this with font lock? How can one override orgmode's font lock rules and restore them if the mode is off?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I've published a number of such minor modes, e.g. https://github.com/Lindydancer/lisp-extra-font-lock

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to add the fontification of a minor mode to the existing fontification of the major mode.

You add [font lock keywords](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) with `font-lock-add-keywords` and remove them with `font-lock-remove-keywords`.

There are many possible structures for the keywords.
See the doc for the variable `font-lock-keywords` for the full list.

One such structure is:

`(MATCHER SUBEXP FACENAME [OVERRIDE])`

- `MATCHER` can be a regexp or a function matching the keyword; The function is called with point at the beginning of the region to be fontified and it receives the end of that region as argument. The function should set the match-data like `re-search-forward`
- `SUBEXP` is the number of the sub-expression of `MATCHER` that should be fontified
- `FACENAME` can be an expression returning the face name to use or a list `(face FACE PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2 ...)`; The second form is handy to set text properties on the keyword.
- `OVERRIDE` Overrides all previous fontification if set to t. Other allowed values are `prepend` and `append` with the obvious meaning.

Normally, you would use the `OVERRIDE` flag with value t, `prepend`, or `append` to overwrite or combine the fontification of the major and the minor mode.

If the rule for the fontification of the match is more complicated you can also set the face and the text properties directly in `MATCHER`. In this case add `MATCHER` as follows to `font-lock-keywords`:

`(font-lock-add-keywords nil '((MATCHER)))`

That technique is often used by org-mode. See, e.g., [`org-fontify-entities`](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/817c0c81e8f6d1dc387956c8c5b026ced62c157c/lisp/org.el#L5666-L5690).

The following Elisp code gives an example for a minor mode that adds `display` text properties to org tables for a fancier presentation:

```el
(defun org+-fancy-table-lines (limit)
  "Draw org tables with fancy lines.
This is a face-lock matcher with arg LIMIT."
  (let ((p (point))
    hline-p
    found)
    (forward-line 0)
    (while (re-search-forward "^[[:space:]]*|" limit t)
      (backward-char)
      (let* ((hline-p (looking-at org-table-hline-regexp))
         (re (if hline-p
             "[|+-]"
           "|"))
         (line-limit (min limit (line-end-position))))
    (when (< (point) p) (goto-char p))
    (while (re-search-forward re line-limit 'noError)
      (let ((b (1- (point)))
        (e (point)))
        (setq found t)
        (cl-case (char-before)
          (?-
           (skip-chars-forward "-")
           (setq e (point))
           (put-text-property b e 'display (make-string (- e b) ?─)))
          (?+
           (put-text-property b e 'display "┼"))
          (?|
           (if hline-p
           (if (eq (char-before b) ?-)
               (put-text-property b e 'display "┤")
             (put-text-property b e 'display "├"))
         (put-text-property b e 'display "│"))))))))
    found))

(defconst org+-fancy-table-keywords '((org+-fancy-table-lines))
  "Font lock keywords for `org+-fancy-table-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode org+-fancy-table-mode
  "Display tables with fancy lines."
  :lighter " ─"
  (if org+-fancy-table-mode
      (progn
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil org+-fancy-table-keywords 'at-end)
    (make-local-variable 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)
    (cl-pushnew 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props))
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil org+-fancy-table-keywords))
  (font-lock-flush))
```

Note, that here we add `display` to the `font-lock-extra-managed-props` list.
That gives font-lock the control over those text properties.
It is a quite drastic measure and may interfere with other commands directly using the `display` property.

Comment: Really nice, thanks! Only the top and the bottom of table (marked by an empty line or a # line) is not completely OK, because at the bottom instead of this https://i.imgur.com/LI3XQPw.png  it should look like this: https://i.imgur.com/bqtgqDj.png   And the same goes for the top.

Comment: @Tom I usually do not put hlines at top or bottom. So I didn't notice.

Comment: you should put this minor mode on Github/Melpa. It really makes org tables look better. Many orgmode users would appreciate it.